# Using an photo Album in a asp.net Repeater

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I'm trying to generate a PhotoAlbum (ListView) inside a Repeater for a portfolio, but I'm unable to get the DataSource to work correctly.

Basically I've got a Flickr Account and a repeater will find images based on an album, and displays these images in a ListView, but I'm unable to get the album id as parameter to work correctly.

Currently I've got the ObjectDataSource code inside the repeater as well, rather then the CodeBehind page, but it is still unable to parse the Album Id correctly.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsPhotos" runat="server" 
                EnablePaging="True" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
                SelectCountMethod="GetPagedSetCount" 
                SelectMethod="GetPagedSet" TypeName="Infrastructure.BLL.FlickrBLL" OnSelecting="odsPhotos_Selecting">
               <SelectParameters>
                       <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProjPhotos")%>" Name="setId"  Type="String" />
               </SelectParameters>
           </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The error I keep getting: Literal content ('

Comment: You may have to set the default value via code; it may not direct support binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is solved by using a single quote rather tan a dobule quote, like @IamStalker suggested. You always have to do this when you use double quotes within the expression.

I think you should leave the Containder.DataItem away as well, like this:

```
<SelectParameters> 
    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue='<%# Eval("ProjPhotos")%>' Name="setId"  Type="String" /> 
</SelectParameters>
```

But do you really need a separate data source for every repeater item (that would be a repeater within a repeater)? I think you should place your object datasource outside the repeater.

The second option is to initialize your data source from the code behind file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <asp:Parameter DefaultValue='<%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProjPhotos")%>' Name="setId"  Type="String" />
```

it might be the literal concatenation problem.